# Eclipse: Multiple monitors and Quick Switch Editor dialog position (Ctrl-E)

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Luna on multiple monitors setup as one single desktop. I resize the Eclipse window to fill the primary monitor (in the center, secondary on the right). When I type Ctrl-E to get the "Quick Switch Editor", the dialog spans over the gap between the monitors and shows up on both (1/2 on each monitor). That is really annoying, but I can't see how to move the dialog position.

How can the dialog position be changed? I don't see any handles on the dialog.

A screenshot doesn't really show the problem, it looks OK there. However, some ascii art may help to show what is really happening:

```
+-----------------------------+  +-----------------------------+
| +-------------------------+ |  |                             |
| |                     +---| |  |--+                          |
| |                     |   | |  |  | <- popup dialog spans    |
| |                     +---| |  |--+    both monitors         |
| |                         | |  |                             |
| |                         | |  |                             |
| | Eclipse window          | |  |                             |
| +-------------------------+ |  |                             |
|   Primary monitor           |  | Secondary monitor           |
+-----------------------------+  +-----------------------------+
```

This is on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5, with Nvidia "TwinView".

Comment: I tried to make this happen in my 2 monitor desktop but could not; the pop-up always stays within the bounds of 1 display. Can you post a screen shot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Edited post to show ascii art

Comment: Looks like a bug, it doesn't do that on Windows (7). Unfortunately that pop-up can't be moved in any way I can find. Please open a bug about it at http://bugs.eclipse.org

Comment: As a work-around, does Ctrl+Shift+E work well enough for you? That's a full dialog that can be resized and moved.

Comment: Yes! that works much better since it is a full dialog. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll choose it.

Comment: Submitted bug 446477: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=446477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Quick Switch Editor* popup (invoked with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) isn't movable or resizable. What you're seeing doesn't happen on Windows, so it's likely a platform-specific bug.

As an alternative, you can use the *Swtich to Editor* dialog (invoked with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>).